# Reading AMQP routing key with Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read off a RabbitMQ broker using apache nifi. It is important that I can retrieve the routing key associated with the message and write the payload and routing key to a file.

I've used python to read the routing key so I'm positive that it is present.

I'm using the ConsumeAMQP processor which links to a PutFile processor. All that gets written is the payload, not the routing key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConsumeAMQP` processor parses the incoming message and forms it into an Apache NiFi `flowfile`. The flowfile structure includes a key/value pair list called *attributes* and the arbitrary bytes of the *content*. According to the ["Additional Details"](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-amqp-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP/additionalDetails.html) section of the `ConsumeAMQP` documentation:

> This processor does two things. It constructs FlowFile by extracting
>   information from the consumed AMQP message (both body and attributes).
>   Once message is consumed a FlowFile is constructed. The message body
>   is written to a FlowFile and its
>   *com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties* are transfered into the
>   FlowFile as attributes. AMQP attribute names are prefixed with *amqp$*
>   prefix.
>
> AMQP Properties The following is the list of available standard AMQP
>   properties which may come with the message: (*"amqp$contentType",
>   "amqp$contentEncoding", "amqp$headers", "amqp$deliveryMode",
>   "amqp$priority", "amqp$correlationId", "amqp$replyTo",
>   "amqp$expiration", "amqp$messageId", "amqp$timestamp", "amqp$type",
>   "amqp$userId", "amqp$appId", "amqp$clusterId"*)

If the attribute you are looking for is not contained here (and unless the naming convention is unusual, it does not appear to be), you should check to see if it is contained in [*com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties*](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/BasicProperties.html) (it does not appear to be). I am not RabbitMQ expert, but from [this link](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-09-03-part4-rabbitmq-for-beginners-exchanges-routing-keys-bindings.html) it looks like the *routing key* is some attribute on a message that an *exchange* registers in order to route the incoming messages. [See also: RabbitMQ "AMQP 0-9-1 Model Explained"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html)

I would check the *amqp$headers* attribute on your incoming messages (you can pause the consuming `PutFile` processor to queue up these flowfiles in the connection and examine them in realtime) to see if you can extract the *routing key* using NiFi Expression Language. An `UpdateAttribute` processor with a dynamic property `routingKey` and an expression like (not tested) `${amqp$headers.routing_key}` would result in a new flowfile attribute called `routingKey` with the value you're looking for. If it is not present there, it would be on the [`com.rabbitmq.client.Envelope` object, accessible via `Envelope.getRoutingKey()`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html), but I do not believe NiFi exposes this object to the processor at this time. A change would need to be made in [`ConsumeAMQP.java @ L101`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-amqp-bundle/nifi-amqp-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/amqp/processors/ConsumeAMQP.java#L101). You can [file a feature request via Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa).

Another thing to keep in mind is that even if you extract the *routing key* to an attribute, `PutFile` very clearly documents that it only prints the flowfile *content* to the file, not the *attributes*. If you need to modify the content of the flowfile to contain attributes, use a `ReplaceText` processor to insert the attributes in a map structure or some other desired format.

Comment: FYI, this is still relevant and here is the current jira for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4303?jql=project%20%3D%20NIFI%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20text%20~%20%22amqp%20routing%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access the routing key (i.e for attribute updating or for flow routing using RouteOnAttribute), use this syntax:

```
${"amqp$routingKey"}
```

Worked for me on NiFi 1.16.0. Took a while to get the exact syntax right and I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.